# Select não retorna nada

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, wpf

Tenho o seguinte metódo:

```
public DataTable Select(bool all = true, string campos = null)
{
    if (all && campos == null)
        _sql.Append("SELECT * FROM ");
    else
        _sql.Append("SELECT " + campos + " FROM ");
    _sql.Append(_tabela);

    _cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql.ToString(), _conexao);
    _conexao.Open();
    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    _dta = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    _dta.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _dta.Fill(ds);

    _dt = ds.Tables[_tabela];

    return _dt;
}
```

Não está acontecendo nenhum erro, porém o `select` está vindo vazio, e a base de dados contém valor.

Existe outra maneira de fazer um `select` e devolver o resultado numa `DataTable`?

Comment: No lugar do "   _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" use isso: "_dta = _cmd.ExecuteReader();"

Comment: @Metalus, fiz isso e agora está dando erro na linha`_dta.Fill(ds);` dizendo que já existe um `DataReader` para este `Command` aberto.

Comment: Vou te dar uma informação adicional que acho que é até mais importante. Pode até se seja mais fácil você identificar o erro. Você não cria uma variável no método. Isto me parece muito errado. Parece que vocês está reaproveitando variáveis de instância. Isto parece bem errado. Não gosto do uso do *underscore* na frente de nomes de variáveis. Você deve estar fazendo isto porque as variáveis devem estar se confundindo muito. Você deve isolar as coisas o máximo possível. Pior, você está vazando recursos e memória para todo lado. É tudo o que não deveria fazer. E nem sei se deveria usar `DataTable`

Comment: @bigown o que você sugeria usar no lugar de `DataTable`?

Comment: Para este caso um `DataReader`. `DataTabele` é um trambolho até poderoso, mas tão ruim que criam o Entity Framework para substituí-lo. Além de ser mais poderoso é mais mais bem feito. Mas o `DataReader` é tudo o que você precisa na maior parte dos casos. Trocar um pelo o outro sem resolver os outros problemas não vai ajudar muito.

Comment: @bigown teria como postar um exemplo de como eu faria para depois de usar o `DataReader` mostrar os dados numa `DataGrid`?

Comment: Não conheço quase nada de WPF mas acho que é isso https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64c9d100-08e4-4f0e-82d0-900571dcf54d/datareader-using-wpf?forum=wpf e http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273697-bind-datareader-datagrid

Comment: @bigown, Obrigado, o primeiro link resolveu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser utilizar o `DataSet`, você pode fazer desse jeito:

```
public DataTable Select(bool all = true, string campos = null)
{
    if (all && campos == null)
        _sql.Append("SELECT * FROM ");
    else
        _sql.Append("SELECT " + campos + " FROM ");
    _sql.Append(_tabela);

    _cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql.ToString(), _conexao);
    _dta = new SqlDataAdapter();
    _dta.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _dta.TableMappings.Add("Table", _tabela); \\ mapeia a tabela
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    _dta.Fill(ds);

    _dt = ds.Tables[_tabela];
    return _dt;
}
```

O principal problema estava no mapear a tabela, algo que você não estava fazendo (encontrei essa informação [nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.90).aspx)).

Quando você usar o `Fill` você não precisa abrir e fechar a conexão explicitamente, pois isso é feito de maneira automática, porém se você abrir a conexão antes de chamar o `Fill`, ela continuará aberta após a execução do mesmo.

Você pode fazer a mesma coisa utilizando direto o `DataTable`, assim:

```
public DataTable Select(bool all = true, string campos = null)
{
    if (all && campos == null)
        _sql.Append("SELECT * FROM ");
    else
        _sql.Append("SELECT " + campos + " FROM ");
    _sql.Append(_tabela);

    _cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql.ToString(), _conexao);
    _dta = new SqlDataAdapter();
    _dta.SelectCommand = _cmd;
    _dt = new DataTable(_tabela); // se ele não foi criado anteriormente
    _dta.Fill(_dt);

    return _dt;
}
```

O `ExecuteNonQuery` que você utilizou, deve ser usado quando você quer executar alguma instrução SQL que não retorna registros do seu banco, por exemplo um `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `CREATE TABLE`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

tente assim:

```
public DataTable ObterDataTable(string conexao, string sql, string nomeTabela)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(nomeTabela);
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao))
    {                
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```